# Make contact form using Google Forms inside GitHub Page

Tags: html, github, markdown, github-pages, google-forms

I use github for hosting my website. I wish to include the possibility for the users to subscribe to a newsletter, which they should do adding their email to a submission form.

I thought that google forms could be a good option to collect the emails, as it is for free, but I don't know how to include it on the github page.

The form I created is [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MQbp1dFP63dnjPbMTKlGIVhC8Je9J6CApiVnnpkSE_Y/edit) one. I would like to add a button inside [this](https://github.com/gvalvano/wss-multiscale-adversarial-attention-gates/blob/master/data.md) markdown file to access the form and subscribe, but I'm not familiar with HTML.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: @Rubén thanks for the suggestions. I added more details in the question

Comment: Thank you for let me know that you added more details but you still should add a brief description of your search/research efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Forms automatically generates HTML code for you to embed the form.

Open the form in Google Drive, then in the top right corner click `Send`. In the popup, there should be a `<>` tab. Click on it and it gives you HTML code that looks like

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/...your_form_url.../viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="382" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
```

You should be able to use that to get the form into your page.